# PHP ODBC to MS SQL Server with cursor not recognizing column aliases

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

When opening ODBC connection with `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` cursor, `odbc_fetch_object` and `odbc_fetch_row` will not recognize any column aliases. `odbc_result` have no such problems.

Would be grateful for tips on solving it.

```
Versions
PHP 5.3
SQL Server 2008
Windows 10
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. `odbc_fetch_row` doesn't do anything with columns, why would it need to "recognize" them? Do you have a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: `odbc_fetch_row` returns associative array where indexes follow column names / aliases. If it can not match alias to data it will fail to execute. This is what's happening in my case. `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC `mangles data somehow and fails to preserve column aliases `count(*) AS total` will not result in `row['total']` since `odbc_fetch_row` wont be able to find `total`